# Listings environment within another environment

Tags: listings, environments, theorems

```
\newtheorem{alg}{Algorithm}[subsection]

\begin{alg}\label{alg:1}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame = single, breaklines = true, numbers = left]
test code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{alg}
```

How can I prevent the above code damaging the code frame like below:

[image]

I have tried using the `caption = ...` argument but that limits my freedom without making a lot more code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) May I ask you what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to label a section of code "Algorithm 4.0.1. (in this case)" using a self defined theorem "alg" for which I can use later to maintain algorithm numbering.

Comment: Do you have different algorithms that don't contain listings?

Comment: Yes, which was my initial problem, so I thought this would work but it then damages the listings frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try defining a new theorem style:

```
\newtheoremstyle{algo}%     <name>
  {\topsep}%                <space above>
  {\topsep}%                <space below>
  {\itshape}%               <body font>
  {}%                       <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}%              <theorem head font>
  {}%                       <punctuation after theorem head>
  {\newline}%               <space after theorem head>
  {}%                       <theorem head spec>
```

and using it for your `alg` theorem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{algo}%     <name>
  {\topsep}%                <space above>
  {\topsep}%                <space below>
  {\itshape}%               <body font>
  {}%                       <indent amount>
  {\bfseries}%              <theorem head font>
  {}%                       <punctuation after theorem head>
  {\newline}%               <space after theorem head>
  {}%                       <theorem head spec>
\theoremstyle{algo}
\newtheorem{alg}{Algorithm}[subsection]

\begin{document}
\begin{alg}\label{alg:1}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame = single, breaklines = true, numbers = left]
test code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{alg}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user2850514 You're welcome. Let me know if you need any more adjustment.